# Show that $(n!+1,(n+1)!+1)=1$.

Tags: proof-verification

**Problem:** Show that $(n!+1,(n+1)!+1)=1$.

**My Attempt:** 
Let $(n!+1,(n+1)!+1)=e$. Then:
$$(n!+1,(n+1)!+1)=(n!+1,(n+1)!+1-((n+1)!+n+1)=(n!+1,-n)$$ 
$=(n!+1,n)\Rightarrow n=ek_1$ and $n!+1=ek_2$ for some $k_1$ and $k_2$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. Observe that $(n-1)!ek_1+1=ek_2\Rightarrow e(k_2-k_1(n-1)!)=1\Rightarrow e=1.$

Is this a valid proof? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The bracket notation is for the greatest common divisor, right?

Comment: Yes it is valid.

Comment: The second step could read $(n!+1,n)=(n!+1-n\cdot(n-1)!,n)=(1,n)=1$, which is in line with the first step and probably more simple.

Comment: 3!+1 does not divide 4!

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. @Did almost missed that step! Thanks.

Comment: Paolo Leonetti's comment should have said @BrianM.Scott to get Brian's attention.

Comment: @AndreasBlass he didn't because he is omniscent :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(n! + 1, (n+1)! +1) = (n! + 1,n \cdot n!)$$ Obviously the two numbers are comprime. This is true, becasue if $p \mid n \cdot n! \implies p \mid n \text{ or } p \mid n!.$ In any case $p \mid n! + 1 - n! = 1$, meaning that they are coprime.